# How can set text box to center of td tag in html table?

Tags: html, css

I spilit the screen with html table,left panel show image and right panel want to show text box,but text box not show the center of td tag,this html code:

```
<table style="width:100vw">
    <tr>
        <td style="width:50vw;height:100vh;" align="left">
            <img src="../Content/45.png" style="display:block;max-width:50vw;max-height:100vh" />
        </td>
        <td style="width:50vh;text-align:center;">
            <div style="top:50%;">
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and this is my output:
[image]

but i want this output:
[image]

How can i solve that?

Comment: https://www.google.com.au/search?q=learn+css&gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=3I93V8PUCIzF0gSvuKuwCg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `div` you use is a block element and as such, will use full width of its parent.

*Updated base on comment:*

*For vertical alignment, use `vertical-align: middle`, updated the CSS rule to this*

*`td {
      padding: 0;
      vertical-align: middle;
    }`*

For horizontal alignment:

In your case you need to set `text-align: center` on the `div` instead of the `td`, like this `<div style="top:50%;text-align:center;">`

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100vw">
  <tr>
    <td style="width:50vw;height:100vh;" align="center">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/600/animals" style="display:block;max-width:50vw;max-height:100vh" />
    </td>
    <td style="width:50vh;">
      <div style="top:50%;text-align:center;">
        <input ID="TextBox1" type="text">
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Or make the div `display: inline-block`, `<div style="top:50%;display: inline-block">`

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100vw">
  <tr>
    <td style="width:50vw;height:100vh;" align="center">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/600/animals" style="display:block;max-width:50vw;max-height:100vh" />
    </td>
    <td style="width:50vh;text-align:center;">
      <div style="top:50%;display: inline-block">
        <input ID="TextBox1" type="text">
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

And may I suggest you put all the styling in the CSS instead of in the markup. It will be so much easier for you to maintain in the long run, and make the code more easy to read and less error prone.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
table {
  width: 100vw;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
  width:50vw;
  height:100vh;
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
.image {
  display:block;
  max-width:50vw;
  max-height:100vh;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img class="image" src="http://lorempixel.com/600/600/animals" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>
        <input id="TextBox1" type="text">
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @behzadrazzaqi Use `vertical-align: middle` on the cell .. will update my answer

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add **css** property to **`td`** i.e. **`vertical-align: middle;`**

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100vw">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/600/animals" style="display:block;max-width:50vw;max-height:100vh" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input ID="TextBox1" type="text">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<td style = "vertical-align:middle" >
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<td>
   <div style="top:50%;">
     <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server">
     </asp:TextBox>

   </div>
</td>
```

on the top put `<table align="center">` and then put this td tag

Answer (score -2):

to put it in center you should do :

```
 <table align="center">
```